# Java Apache POI XWPF writing to Template - Corrupted word file

Tags: java, groovy, apache-poi

I am opening a word file and using it as a template. I have run both my test program and my actual program. In my JUnit test, which is in Groovy, everything works fine, and I output the file with no problems. When I run the exact same code in my application and try to open the word doc (actually docx) I get the error message, **"The file TestGenerated.docx cannot be opened because there are problems with the contents."** Under the Details it says **"The parameter is incorrect. Location: Part: /word/document.xml, Line: 2, Column: 0"**

The code is below:

```
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.util.Units;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlCursor;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class TestInJava {

XWPFDocument document;
FileOutputStream out;
File output;

public TestInJava() {
    try {
        //This file is the first you find when you search for sample word docx file

        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\usmcphysicist\\Downloads\\trans_jour.docx");
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
        document = new XWPFDocument(in);
        output = new File(FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getHomeDirectory() + "/TestGenerated.docx");
        out = new FileOutputStream(output);

        XWPFRun titleRun = document.getParagraphs().get(7).getRuns().get(0);
        XWPFRun wordsRun = document.getParagraphs().get(20).createRun();
        XWPFParagraph pictureParagraph = document.getParagraphs().get(40);

        titleRun.setText("Outputting Apache POI", 0);
        wordsRun.setText("Something in the body", 0);
        wordsRun.setColor("42f45c");

        File picture = new File("C:\\Users\\usmcphysicist\\Pictures\\flag200.png");

        XWPFRun pictureRun = pictureParagraph.createRun();
        try {
            pictureRun.addPicture(new FileInputStream(picture), XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG, file.getAbsolutePath(),
                    Units.toEMU(200), Units.toEMU(112));
        } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Picture didn't print");
        }

        XWPFParagraph tableParagraph = document.getParagraphs().get(50);

        XmlCursor cursor = tableParagraph.getCTP().newCursor();
        XWPFTable table = document.insertNewTbl(cursor);
        XWPFTableRow row1 = table.getRow(0);

        row1.setRepeatHeader(true);

        row1.getCell(0).setText("Release Order");
        row1.addNewTableCell();
        row1.getCell(1).setText("Episode");
        row1.addNewTableCell();
        row1.getCell(2).setText("Name");


        XWPFTableRow row = table.createRow();
        row.getCell(0).setText(Integer.toString(1));
        row.getCell(1).setText(Integer.toString(4));
        row.getCell(2).setText("A New Hope");

        row = table.createRow();
        row.getCell(0).setText(Integer.toString(2));
        row.getCell(1).setText(Integer.toString(5));
        row.getCell(2).setText("Empire Strikes Back");

        row = table.createRow();
        row.getCell(0).setText(Integer.toString(3));
        row.getCell(1).setText(Integer.toString(6));
        row.getCell(2).setText("Return of the Jedi");

        row = table.createRow();
        row.getCell(0).setText(Integer.toString(4));
        row.getCell(1).setText(Integer.toString(1));
        row.getCell(2).setText("The Phantom Menace");

        row = table.createRow();
        row.getCell(0).setText(Integer.toString(5));
        row.getCell(1).setText(Integer.toString(2));
        row.getCell(2).setText("Attack of the Clones");

        row = table.createRow();
        row.getCell(0).setText(Integer.toString(6));
        row.getCell(1).setText(Integer.toString(3));
        row.getCell(2).setText("Revenge of the Sith");

        document.write(out);
        out.close();
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(output);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "IoException");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: The fact that the error message says, GeneratedFile.docx, but that doesn't exist anywhere in your code is a bit of a red flag. Are you sure you're using the most up to date version of this code in your application? Or is there some other part of your code that we aren't seeing?

Comment: Yes, good catch, that was from a different attempt, edited to the corrected error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up being an error within Apache Poi 3.16 in inserting images into the document. When I upgraded to POI 3.17 all of the problems were fixed.